# Qt drag drop UNC path

Tags: qt

when dragging a file from path

`\\Nearlinestorage\anc\sequences\anc_SH_005\2d\cgRenders\Maya_Files\28.07.11`

in lineEdit area it cuts `\\nearlinestorage` when reading `ui->lineedit->text()`

how is it possible to get the whole path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved. Problem is in the droparea::dropevent(QDropEvent *event). 
I replaced

QString url = urlList.at(i).path();

with

QString url = urlList.at(i).toLocalFile();

I get proper result ( as expected ).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the QLineEdit doesn't have a minimum number of characters set.

Comment: this happens to only unc path or path starting with //

Comment: any other clue. It occurs to me that qlineedit is thinking of the text as some unc path or so hence it displays from \anc\sequences\.....

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what's happening. QLineEdit shouldn't treat file paths any differently, it should just treat it as text. Could you maybe post more code?

Comment: ok. i know what is causing it but not clear how to rectify it. needed dragdrop function so i used \n[link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/draganddrop-dropsite-droparea-cpp.html). see QList<QUrl> urlList = mimeData->urls(); This area is causing the problem